# Cannot load sql table to r through SparkR

Tags: java, r, apache-spark, sparkr, sparklyr

I'm trying to load an SQL table in R through sparkR. I have the following code:

```
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = "C:/Users/hms/Desktop/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7",
           HADOOP_HOME = "C:/Users/hms/Desktop/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/tmp/hadoop")
.libPaths(c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib"), .libPaths()))

library(SparkR)

sc<-sparkR.session( enableHiveSupport = FALSE, master="local[*]",
                    sparkHome=Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"),
                    sparkConfig = list(spark.driver.memory="2g",
                                       spark.driver.extraClassPath="C:/Users/hms/Desktop/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/sqljdbc4.jar",
                                       spark.executor.extraClassPath="C:/Users/hms/Desktop/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/sqljdbc4.jar",
                                       spark.sql.warehouse.dir="C:/Users/hms/Desktop/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/tmp/hadoop/bin") )



persons <- read.jdbc("jdbc:sqlserver://xpto//xpto:1433;databaseName=XPTO_XPTO", "table.XPTO", user = "XPTO", password = "XPTO")
```

When I run this code as it is, I get the following error:

```
Error in invokeJava(isStatic = FALSE, objId$id, methodName, ...) : 
      com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host srvptsqlsdd02//sddev02_2k12, port 1433 has failed. Error: "null. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.ConvertConnectExceptionToSQLServerException(SQLServerException.java:241)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket(IOBuffer.java:2243)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(IOBuffer.java:491)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1309)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.conn
```

Can someone give a hint on what can be the problem?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by doing

```
persons <- read.jdbc("jdbc:sqlserver://xpto\\xpto:1433...
```